# Show contents of categories, php dynamical tables

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to print the contents of items by their category in a web page in this manner:

Category1:
Item1 item2 item3
item4 item5...

Category2
item1 item2 ...

This my PHP code:

```
$cat="";
$maxcols = 3;
$i = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($i == $maxcols) {
        $i = 0;
        echo "</tr><tr>"; 
    }

    if($row['name']!=$cat)
    { 
        echo "<table>
        <tr><td collspan='3'>".$row['name']."</td></tr>
        <tr>";
    }

    echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
    $cat=$row['name'];
    $i++;

}

while ($i <= $maxcols) {
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    $i++;
    echo "</table>";
}
```

What I am getting is:

```
<table>
<tr><td collspan='3'>Archivers</td></tr>
<tr><td>7-Zip</td><td>IZArc</td><td>dfssdfsdf sdfsdf</td></tr><tr><td>fgdgdfgd</td><td>sdfsdfsdfsdf dsfsdfsd</td><table>
<tr><td collspan='3'>Benchmark</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fresh Diagnose</td><td>&nbsp;</td></table>
```

What I want to get is:

```
<table>
<tr><td collspan='3'>Archivers</td></tr>
<tr><td>7-Zip</td><td>IZArc</td><td>dfssdfsdf sdfsdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>fgdgdfgd</td><td>sdfsdfsdfsdf dsfsdfsd</td>**<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>**
<table>
<tr><td collspan='3'>Benchmark</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fresh Diagnose</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but can't you just add "\r\n" to get the new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have very 'messy' code. I suppose you need some more code to add the part between the stars, but I think you should use a cleaner approach.

I suppose you are using mysql, which supports the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)-function. It would be wise to use that in this case.

Make a query:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT( title SEPERATOR '|') as titles FROM your_database GROUP BY name
```

The results per category are now in one row.

```
//Amount of rows
$maxcols = 3;

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
  //The seperator needs to be something that isn't in the values it seperates
  //This creates an array with the titles for this category
  $titles = explode( '|', $row['titles'] );

  echo '
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="' .$maxcols. '">' .$row['name']. '</td>
    </tr>';

  //$offset + $i is the position in the array of titles
  $offset = 0;

  //This loop ensures each row is properly opened and closed
  while( $offset < count( $titles ) ) {

    echo '<tr>';
    //This will ensure each row has $maxcols td's in it
    for( $i = 0; $i < $maxcols; $i++ ) {
      if( isset( $titles[ $offset + $i ] ) ) {
        echo '<td>' .$titles[ $offset + $i ]. '</td>';
      } else {
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      }
    }
    $offset += $maxcols;
    echo '</tr>';
  }

  echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Sumurai8! Your idea works great. Here is my php code:

```
<?php
include_once('include/db.inc.php');

$sql="SELECT m.name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.title order by s.title SEPARATOR '|' ) as titles FROM menu m, software s where m.id=s.category
GROUP BY m.name
order by m.name";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$cat="";

$maxcols = 3;
//$i = 0;

echo "
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>content</title>
         <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
         <meta content='Software Details' name='description'>
<link href='styles/fontstyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
<link href='styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
</head>

<body class='body'>";


while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
  //The seperator needs to be something that isn't in the values it seperates
  //This creates an array with the titles for this category
  $titles = explode( '|', $row['titles'] );

  echo "
<table>
<tr><td colspan='" .$maxcols. "'>" .$row['name']. "</td></tr> \n";

  //$offset + $i is the position in the array of titles
  $offset = 0;

  //This loop ensures each row is properly opened and closed
  while( $offset < count( $titles ) ) {

    echo "<tr>";
    //This will ensure each row has $maxcols td's in it
    for( $i = 0; $i < $maxcols; $i++ ) {
      if( isset( $titles[ $offset + $i ] ) ) {
        echo "<td>" .$titles[ $offset + $i ]. "</td>";
      } else {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
      }
    }
    $offset += $maxcols;
    echo "</tr> \n";
  }

  echo "</table><br> \n";
}
```

This is the output, just the way I want it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>content</title>
         <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
         <meta content='Software Details' name='description'>
<link href='styles/fontstyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
<link href='styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
</head>

<body class='body'>
<table>
<tr><td colspan='3'>Archivers</td></tr> 
<tr><td>7-Zip</td><td>IZArc</td><td>dfssdfsdf sdfsdf</td></tr> 
<tr><td>fgdgdfgd</td><td>sdfsdfsdfsdf dsfsdf</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
</table><br> 

<table>
<tr><td colspan='3'>Benchmark</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Fresh Diagnose</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
</table><br> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of echo'ing the first part with the doctype, you can instead stop the php block with `?>` and start it again after the html with `<?php`.

Comment: I know that, but does it really matter? I think that this is a question of habit. I do not know if I am right, I am new in PHP :)

Comment: Both work perfectly fine, but a string is usually not 'coloured' by an IDE when editing a document, while if you close the php-tag, the IDE will usually colour your html as if it is html, instead of a string.